# POD-ness with nested structs/classes

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have a question concerning POD-ness. I expected that if B is non-POD and B is a member in A, so would A be non-POD.
However the following code example outputs "10", hence B is correctly considered non-POD but A is.

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    struct B
    {
        std::string s;
    };
};
std::cout << std::is_pod<A>::value;
std::cout << std::is_pod<A::B>::value;
```

Is this a bug in GCC? I'm using "c++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180312".
I don't see the sense in this behaviour. Lets say I wanted to optimize buffer allocations and use the POD-check in order to determine whether I would have to use new or can use malloc/realloc for a specific type. I would be totally wrong to use malloc to allocate storage for A.
Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` has a type `A::B` in it.

Instances of `A` have no instance of `A::B` in it. There is only a definition of the type, but no instantiation of it.

Add `B b;` to `A` and your anomaly goes away.